# Transfinity of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: order-theory, cardinals, foundations

I have read in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899795/588260
that $\mathbb{Q}$ is 'larger' than $\mathbb{Z}$.

I assume it has to do with transfinities in which the one of $\mathbb{Q}$ has a relation of order so that it above the one of $\mathbb{Z}$, but I haven't read about that yet. I am just curious if someone can explain to me this concept, I know very basics of transfinity, like what $\aleph _0$ means, but not that much.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb Q$. But $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: The page you're refrencing seems to be dead. Prehaps you mean that there exists an injective order preserving map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ but not the other way around?

Comment: The link you are citing does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood your link. The statement

> Most people probably think that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a larger set than $\mathbb{Q}$  (and also probably don't know what 'larger' means)

Is an example of a *misconception* — a popularly held belief that is not actually true.

The relevant technical notion here is *cardinality*. The phrase "X is a larger set than Y" is a colloquialism for "The cardinality of $X$ is greater than the cardinality of $Y$".

Showing there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ proves that the proposition "The cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$ is greater than the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}$" is false.

---

Incidentally, I don't think I've every heard the term "transfinity" outside of some... eccentric articles.

The term "transfinite" does appear in mathematics, but almost always in a very niche usage: specifically referring to sequences (and things related to sequences) whose index set continues beyond the natural numbers. For example, the sequence consisting of all natural numbers, and then followed by the ordinal number $\omega$ would be an example of a "transfinite sequence".

Instead of the word "transfinity", I think the words you're looking for are along the lines of "infinite set" or "infinite cardinality".

Also note that in mathematics, "infinity" is usually used as a *proper* noun — e.g. to refer to the extended real number $+\infty$. The adjectival form "infinite" is more common. E.g. one says "an infinite set" rather than "an infinity", or "you have infinitely many things" rather than "you have an infinity of things".